# Is there a way to overlay keyboard usage on-screen?

Tags: macos, on-screen-keyboard

I want to be able to create videos (screen recordings) that show the keys I am pressing on my keyboard. E.g., I hold Shift, and Shift is shown on-screen as I hold it.

Is there a way to do this on an OS X machine?

Comment: I believe you want http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: “Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.” As long as they don’t use a Mac? What’s the real issue here?

Comment: There is no issue. I was just saying that for this type of question you may have better luck on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlanH. System preferences > Keyboard > Show Keyboard, emozji... Does't work for you ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/U5K6Q.jpg

Comment: @pun: Awesome. I didn’t realize that it showed what you were typing; I thought it was merely a mouse-based way to type… that should work! Thanks!